# convert string to the "base script" view

Tags: string, tcl

I have string like this

```
set string "a\[f\]"
```

When I have printed this string I get this result

```
a[f]
```

I know why it works like this, but I want to print

```
a\[f\]
```

and also I don't want to change the first string.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you use braces to quote the text,  you'll get what you want: `set string {a\[f\]}` -- does that count as "changing the string"?

Comment: I want to create string1 from string, which value will be a\f\]

Comment: glenn jackman In my task I can't change the first string

Comment: Well, you are bound by the [rules of Tcl](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm) -- in a double quoted string, backslash substitution will occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're stuck with

```
set string "a\[f\]"
```

then you can do

```
set string1 [regsub -all {\W} $string {\\&}]
```

which adds an escape to all non-word characters.

There's no way to know exactly which characters in the original string were escaped.